# Unity C# UIs resizing after trying to build & run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever I try to build & run my 2d unity game it resizes all of the UIs, while it doesn't do this in the testing scene in unity. I've tried changing the canvas scaler to a few different settings with no luck.

In Testing:
[image]

In Build: [image]

Comment: what platform do you use to run your build? if the objects on the screens above are inside of canvas, do you use canvasscaler?

Comment: It is unlikely that you are using it in this type of game but PixelPerfect camera component can cause it for certain resolutions.

Comment: If you set the appropriate aspect ratio/size preset in the unity `Game` window, then you will see exactly how it will look in the build and can adjust ui accordingly.  I think you have a left and right offset, probably using one of the stretch anchors.  It can also be caused by using fixed sizes for those elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing in the Canvas:

- Canvas Scaler --> UI Scale Mode
  to: **Scale with Screensize**
- Set the **Reference Resolution X Y**
  to your Resolution *(for example: X
  1920 Y 1080)*
- Set **Match** to: 0.5

This should Scale and position the UI accordingly to your Screensize

I hope this helps